# Screen time-out during programming enforce me to press wake up button at every turn

Tags: android, screen, sleep

I use Eclipse for programming my android device. I connect the device to my computer via USB. Everything is fine but I write some code that can take a bit long time and I pressed F11, my device had already gone to sleep and its screen had gone to off. At every turn, I have to press its button to wake it up. If I make its screen time-out longer in the settings, then my device becomes **very hot**.

Is there any solution which can provide that it can turn its screen on to show my application when I press F11. It may be a code piece that I can temporarily add into my application during development phase or a setting adjustment for my device.

Thanks

Comment: which device you are using ?

Comment: Go to Development Options -> Stay awake while plugged in.

Comment: In settings->developeroptions->Stayawake (tick it)

Comment: it becames too hot if I turn on "stay awake" option.

Comment: Have you tried turning the screen brightness down?

Comment: Yes, I tried reducing the brightness. It works. At least, it doesn't become too hot anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By expanding to Tushar's comment,

- Go to Settings,
- Select Developer Options,
- you will see following screen, Tick the "USB Debugging" option

[image]

Comment: as far as I know, it is already impossible to use the device for debugging if "USB debuggin" option isn't checked so I have already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the screen to never timeout when plugged in/charging. This is available through Settings > Developers Options (or Advanced Settings).

[image: Advanced Settings Screenshot]